# Implicit construction of std::string does not happen during copy-initialization

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to copy-initialize my `CObj` class as follows in the `main()` function:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class CObj
{
public:
   CObj(std::string const& str) : m_str(str) { std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }

   ~CObj() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }

private:
   std::string m_str;
};

int main()
{
    CObj obj = "hello";

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

However, the line `CObj obj = "hello"` fails to compile even though `std::string` is implicitly constructible from a `char const*`. According to my understanding here, this should work. Any reason why it doesn't? If I do this it works:

```
CObj obj = std::string("hello");
```

Comment: You can only have one user defined implicit conversion in an implicit conversion sequence. You attempt two: from string literal to `string` and from `string` to `CObj`.

Comment: "hello" is a `const char[6]`, not a `std::string const& str` and only 1 user defined conversion is allowed

Comment: Hang on you're about to see a quote from C++ standards (not me) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal `"Hello"` has type `const char[6]` : in order to call your constructor, two conversions are required : one to `std::string` and a second one to `CObj` .

But C++ only allows one user-defined conversion when doing an implicit conversion :

C++ Standard section § 12.3/4 [class.conv]

> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for implicit type conversions
>
> [...]
>
> At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

---

This is why this works :

```
CObj obj = std::string("hello");
```

Or this:

```
CObj obj("hello");
```

Or you could provide a constructor that accepts a `const char*` :

```
CObj(const char* cstr) : m_str(cstr) { ... }
```

I would always advise to make such constructors `explicit` to avoid unwanted implicit conversions, unless it really brings something to the user of the class.

Comment: I think you should/could suggest to create another constructor that accepts `const char *`

Comment: Or he could just write `CObj obj( "hello" );`, which _should_ work.

Answer (score 2):

You are limited to at most one user-defined conversion when instantiating an object (i.e. `char[6]` -> `std::string` and `std::string` -> `CObj` is one conversion too many).

To fix:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals; // this is necessary
                                                    // for the literal conversion

    CObj obj = "hello"s; // note the extra "s", (which constructs a std::string)

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```